# Java proguard keep name of field and method that have FXML Annotation

Tags: java, javafx, proguard, fxml

i need to keep method and field name that have the @FXML annotation,

i try this but it'dosen't work

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @proguard.annotation.FXML <methods>;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate Proguard obfuscation in my JavaFX's IntelliJ artifact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445960/how-to-integrate-proguard-obfuscation-in-my-javafxs-intellij-artifact)

Comment: @pety that question doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @proguard.annotation.FXML <methods>;
}
```

Only tells Prodguard not to rename Methods that are annotaded with FXML. You also need to tell it not to remove the FXML attribute:

```
-keepattributes javafx.fxml.FXML
```

You can also tell ProGuard to adapt the fxml files in your application with

```
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml
```