# How to create executable obfuscated jar for a JavaFX application?

Tags: maven, ant, javafx, proguard, obfuscation

I need to create an executable jar of my JavaFX application. I have done that using ANT. I also need to obfuscate this jar. When I obfuscate using proguard, it is no more executable. Please provide inputs if anyone has worked on it. TIA.

Comment: You may want to go through this blog - [Obfuscate Your JavaFX Application](http://java.dzone.com/articles/obfuscate-your-javafx) and this answer - [How to integrate Proguard obfuscation in my JavaFX's IntelliJ artifact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445960/how-to-integrate-proguard-obfuscation-in-my-javafxs-intellij-artifact)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I have done this. With this, the jar is getting obfuscated. But it is not executable. I want it to be executable jar.

Comment: Is a main class in the manifest after the obfuscoring process? What is the error message? Is there any error message?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner contents of MAINFEST is same in my normal jar (executable) and obfuscated jar (not executable). But I see a "?" in obfuscated jar's MANIFEST.. Not sure what it is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.

I've uploaded a [working project for using proguard](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/08-build-with-proguard) when using maven with javafx-maven-plugin, the kudos goes to [Maxim Dobryakov](https://github.com/maxd/).

Comment: Hey thank for the plug-in. First off I followed your project and it creates an obfuscated jar, but the jar in the jfx/native/ folder isn't obfuscated. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I saw the same problem, the jar bundled in the installer ,which is generated by mvn jfx:native, doesn't get obfuscated for some reason